Cannot install Tensorflowjs
I have a keras machine learning model titled "melanoma_binary_classifer.keras", and I am trying to convert it to tf.js layer format, and load it into tensorflow.js. I am doing this by loading the model in jupyter notebook, importing tensorflowjs as tfjs, and converting like so:
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, tfjs_target_dir)

The above code is from the documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras
HOWEVER, in the documentation it says "pip install tensorflowjs", where I am getting this error: 
Which does not let me, or allow me, to execute my code below in the jupyter notebook: 
My tensorflow version is 2.6.0.

Have you used pip to fetch an updated jaxlib?  The problem here is not tensorflow or tensorflowjs.

How about installing the latest version of tensorflowjs?
